# C++ Threading error: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am getting into threading in C++ and was going some testing and got this error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static vector<string> thisVector;

void thread1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
        thisVector.push_back(to_string(i));
    }
    cout << "Finished 1" << endl;
    return;
}

void thread2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
        thisVector.push_back(to_string(i));
    }
    cout << "Finished 2" << endl;
    return;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    thread first(thread1);
    thread second(thread2);
    first.join();
    second.join();
    cout << "done threading" << endl;
    cout << thisVector.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The weird thing is, sometimes I get the correct output, so 800. Sometimes I get a number slightly lower than that for I don't know what reason??? And sometimes I get the following error:

malloc: *** error for object 0x100400028: pointer being freed was not allocated

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: vectors aren't thread safe so the whole sample is dodgy (and lucky to ever get 800 items)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any type of structure I can use to play with a large amount of data like vectors or unordered maps?

Comment: You can use vectors etc, but you need to wrap (some) methods with mutexes etc to safely allow access from 2 threads. One way divide your operations into read and write. Write ops "block" everything. Read ops only block write ops. - i.e. 2 threads can say "how big is the collection" at the same time but one thread can't say "how big is the collection" when the other is in the middle of adding an item.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Tried with Mutex and it works!

Comment: Vectors are thread safe if you pre-allocate them and put the strings from each thread into distinct locations (not using push_back(). Otherwise, as stated, you need to protect them with a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::vector` is not thread safe. You have two execution threads modifying the same `std::vector` concurrently. Operations on a `std::vector` should, in this case, be protected by a mutex.

The result of this is undefined behavior. As you've observed, sometimes it might work, sometimes wrong results get produced but the program completes successfully, sometimes the program crashes. This is what "undefined behavior" means.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth reading The C++ Programming Language, it covers subjects of interest like : threads, tasks, but also at higher conceptual level future/promise, packaged_task, async.

In your case, you don't only deal with concurrency. You have to deal with shared data of concurrent threads. The way you programmed it does not guarantee any order of execution. That is why you get those *strange* results.

The error message you mentioned is likely to be because of concurrent access to the shared vector and it says what is wrong: a pointer is being freed (delete), but was not allocated beforehand. You don't see the pointer, it's an internal member of vector.

Your solution is to use a mutex to make sure that whenever a data is pushed back into the vector it does not get interrupted by the other concurrent thread and finishes appropriately, so that the next push_back starts only when the previous one has finished.

You can use a global variable for mutex. Then you need to deal appropriately with locking/unlocking, i.e. you must say when to acquire a mutex (before push_back) and when to release it (after push_back). Since you use only one mutex this should be fairly simple and should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static vector<string> thisVector;
//Global MUTEX
mutex mv;
//

void thread1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
        //Lock before and unlock  after push back
        mv.lock();
        thisVector.push_back(to_string(i));
        mv.unlock();
    }
    cout << "Finished 1" << endl;
    return;
}

void thread2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
        mv.lock();
        thisVector.push_back(to_string(i));
        mv.unlock();
    }
    cout << "Finished 2" << endl;
    return;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    thread first(thread1);
    thread second(thread2);
    first.join();
    second.join();
    cout << "done threading" << endl;
    cout << thisVector.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```